# Java sort method that supports method chaining?

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons

Are there convenience methods for sorting arrays and collections that support method chaining in Java or popular open source utility libraries such as Guava or Apache-Commons?  Something that I could throw into a snippet like this:

```
private static final List<String> myStrings = collections.unmodifiableList(
    SortUtils.sortList(
        Arrays.asList(new String["b","a"])
    )
);
```

Then `myStrings` would contain "a", and "b" (in that order).

I could write methods like this myself, but I don't want to re-invent the wheel if they are already available in the libraries that I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for [`Ordering.sortedCopy`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#sortedCopy%28java.lang.Iterable%29) in Guava, but that's fluent in the comparator, not the collection.

Something fluent on the list might appear in Guava's `FluentIterable`, probably coming out in Guava release 12.

Comment: I don't really care about the copy.  Probably doesn't matter that it does it, but would be ok without it.   Know of anything for arrays that calls Arrays.sort then return the array?

Comment: No, nothing.  (Arrays and generics are still super awkward.)

Comment: Actually, though, if you're just planning to wrap it in an unmodifiable list, then `Ordering.immutableSortedCopy` is even more likely to be your friend.